# web application using tcl/tk

Tags: tcl

I want to develop a simple web based resource reservation system using TCL/TK. 
Please let me know some good tutorials or links to start with.
Also some good examples please.

Thanks,
Ramya

Answer (score 3):

[OpenACS](http://openacs.org) has a [room reservation module](http://fisheye.openacs.org/browse/OpenACS/openacs-4/contrib/packages/room-reservation) included. OpenACS is written in TCL. There are tutorials available [here](http://openacs.org/xowiki/docs-dev-tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Note that [Tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/Tk) is a library to program GUIs; it's not a part of Tcl which is a language (and its [reference implementation](ftp://ftp.tcl.tk/pub/tcl/)).

But there *is* a project which provides for programming web presentation layer in a way resembling programming GUIs with Tk—it's called [Æjaks](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17422).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kostix. Which one would you suggest for me to develop a web based resource reservation system.

Comment: I don't quite parse your comment, @ramya, as it mentioned exactly one system which has anything to do with web applications. What did you mean?